# React-Native application crashes in android 12 after updating targetSdkVersion to 31

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, crash

```
Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

I've no idea where to make changes in order to run the application. Below android 12 application working fine.

I've no idea what to try for the possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

increase your  firebase version and add iid in your app/gradle

`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"`

`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase messaging:22.0.0"`

Comment: That doesn't work, it is still crashing apk with the same error message